# Why won't this data display

Tags: c#, angular

I am learning Angular, and I started with the sample project in Visual Studio called Angular5TF1. There is a menu choice in the sample called "Fetch Data" which emulates data retrieval from the server. I copied this method and its classes and pages and am trying to make it retrieve data from a method I wrote - it does not work..

I copied the "FetchData" method and its classes and pages from the sample and am trying to make it retrieve data from a method I wrote. The return value shows the correct values, but when I try to display one of the values from the array, it returns undefined. Also, I return 10 values, the for loop prints 10 lines but they are all blank. Can someone please explain why and help me get this working? Thanks in advance.

From the component html:

```
<h1>Interests</h1>

<div class="col-lg-12">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="col-lg-10">
    Interest:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="txtInterest" />&nbsp;<button (click)="test()">Add...</button>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <p *ngIf="!personalInterests"><em>Loading Interests, Please Wait...</em></p>
</div>


<table class='table' *ngIf="personalInterests">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Interest Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let interest of personalInterests">
            <td>{{ interest.InterestName }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

From the component

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
//import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';

@Component({
    selector: 'interests',
    templateUrl: './interests.component.html'
})
export class InterestsComponent {
    public personalInterests: PersonalInterest[];

    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Interest/Interests').subscribe(result => {
            this.personalInterests = result.json() as PersonalInterest[];
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }

    public test() {
        alert(this.personalInterests[1].InterestName);
    }
}

interface PersonalInterest {
    InterestName: string;
}
```

Aaaaaand from the controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class InterestController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IEnumerable<Interest> Interests()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            IEnumerable<Interest> PersInt =  Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(index => new Interest
            {
                InterestName = string.Format("Test_{0:00}", index)
            });

            //To simulate a slow connection
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return PersInt;
        }

        public class Interest
        {
           public string InterestName { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

Comment: In the client code (Angular) try using `interestName` rather than `InterestName`. Camel case; could make all the difference.

Comment: try to use console.log to see what data is store into personalInterests.

Comment: WOW, changed to Camel case and my alert now gets a valid value - :)) Grid now displays. Thank you so much! I fought this all day! Should I always use camel case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Camel Case fixed the issue.